# Fastest way to store and retrieve arrays

Tags: python, sql, arrays, database, nosql

I'm working on a project where I have to store about 17 million `128`-dimensional integer arrays e.g `[1, 2, 1, 0, ..., 2, 6, 4]` and I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to do it.

The perfect solution would be one that makes it fast to both store and retrieve the arrays, since I need to access ALL of them to make calculations. With such a vast amount of data, I obviously can't store them all in memory in order to make calculations, so accessing batches of arrays should be as fast as possible.

I'm working in Python.

What do you recommend ? Using a `DB` (`SQL` vs `NOSQL` ?), storing it in a text file, using python's Pickle?

Comment: pandas is pretty fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the size of your dataset (34 GB, assuming 16 bit integers), storing your dataset as HDF5 with [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) would probably be the optimal choice.

PyTables was specifically developed to work efficiently with extremely large datasets that can't be loaded at once in memory. Also, have a look at the [compression options](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/optimization.html#compression-issues) that can improve I/O efficiency and save some disk space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not so big with numpy arrays, if your integers are 8 bits.   `a=numpy.ones((17e6,128),uint8)` is created in less than  a second on my computer.  but `ones((17e6,128),uint16)` is difficult, and  `ones((17e6,128),uint64)` crashed.